# React Native SDK runtime permission error

Tags: android, reactjs, npm, react-native

React Native running android says the new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions. The old target SDK 24 does though, so how do you fix it?
 [Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxaLA.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the following attributes in the file [project path]/android/app/build.gradle ,

```
........
.........

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kotac"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}

 .................
 .............
```

as needed

Answer (score 12):

Uninstall old version of your app.